# Assistance with JSON from URL

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to fetch JSON from a URL in Java, and output results.
Here is my json, from www.thebluealliance.com/api/v2/match/2015arc_qm1. I want to get the match_number, and the scores from the blue and red alliances, and print it to my console. I am using GSON (Google JSON). For example, I would want this code to return 1, 91, 97...

```
{
  "comp_level": "qm",
  "match_number": 1,
  "videos": [],
  "time_string": null,
  "set_number": 1,
  "key": "2015arc_qm1",
  "time": 1429795800,
  "score_breakdown": {
    "blue": {
      "auto": 0,
      "foul": 12
    },
    "red": {
      "auto": 0,
      "foul": 0
    }
  },
  "alliances": {
    "blue": {
      "score": 91,
      "teams": [
        "frc1706",
        "frc2907",
        "frc2363"
      ]
    },
    "red": {
      "score": 97,
      "teams": [
        "frc2914",
        "frc360",
        "frc207"
      ]
    }
  },
  "event_key": "2015arc"
}
```

My Java code can be found below

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String sURL = "http://www.thebluealliance.com/api/v2/match/2015arc_qm
                1?X-TBA-App-Id=frc1810:alex-webber:v01";
URL url = new URL(sURL);
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
request.connect();
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request
                .getContent()));
JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement results = rootobj
                .getAsJsonObject().get("match_number")
                .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("alliances").get(4)
                .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("blue").getAsJsonObject().get("score");
String match = results.getAsString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out, I did not test it, but from what i see in your JSON document, you have a couple of issues in your code, alliances is not an a json array, also blue and red are not json arrays, they are json objects based on what i see in your json document,

```
JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement match_number = rootobj.get("match_number");
JsonObject alliances = rootobj.getAsJsonObject("alliances");
JsonElement blue = alliances.getAsJsonObject("blue").get("score");
JsonElement red  = alliances.getAsJsonObject("red").get("score");

System.out.println(match_number.getAsString()+","+blue.getAsString()+","+red.getAsString());
```